# Slow Startup for setup SignalR connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

Setup a simple SignalR Chat web application using the [Microsoft tutorial code](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc).

```
!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.--> 
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
            // Add the message to the page. 
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name) 
                + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
        };
        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
        // Set initial focus to message input box.  
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
```

It's running OK when debugging locally, I can send message immediately after putting in a username. But when deployed onto the Azure, after entering the username, I have to wait like 5 seconds before I can submit a new message (no response clicking Send button), but after this first message, for all the following messages I can send instantly.

For me, it looks like it is slow when setting up the initial connection (`$.connection.hub.start()`).

Is this normal? How can I improve the performance of this simple application?

Comment: So is it slow on the start up, or is it slow when you're sending a request to the server? What's your hub code look like?

Comment: It seems to me that you did not enable websockets on Azure. SignalR is trying to start the connection using websockets transport and when this fails it tries to use serverSentEvents as a fallback (and if this does not work it tries longPolling). You can confirm this by opening the debugger tools and checking the requests SignalR makes.

Comment: @Pawel, You are absolutely right! It was using longPolling. Problem fixed by enabling the WebSocket on Azure, and using HTTPS to access. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default websockets are not enabled on Azure and, by default, the client tries different transports starting from webSockets. If websockets does not work it will fall back to serverSentEvents and finally to longPolling. This takes time. Make sure you turn on websockets on Azure or specify that you want to use only serverSentEvents and longPolling transports.

Comment: could you please have a look at my follow up questions: [SignalR Azure Cloud Service with Service Bus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345867/signalr-azure-cloud-service-with-service-bus)?