# SignalR Azure Cloud Service with Service Bus

Tags: asp.net, websocket, signalr, azureservicebus, azure-cloud-services

I have built a simple Chat application using SignalR followed the [tutorial there](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc), which works great.

Then I followed the tutorial of [SignalR Scaleout with Azure Service Bus](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus), also from Microsoft.

So I have completed all the following steps:

- Created a new Cloud Service on Azure Portal
- Created a new Service Bus namespace on Azure Portal
- Created a Windows Azure Cloud Service with a SignalR ASP.NET Web Role
- Setup the SignalR Web Role running on 2 instances (VM Size: Small)
- Deployed the Cloud Service to the Azure Cloud Service.

But I can't get the SignalR Chat application to work. Can't start the hub.

I noticed it tried to use longPolling and shows status Cancelled/Abort in the browser's debugging tool (Chrome) with the following error in the console:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.cloudapp.net/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=KOlz9psd6yCqvYjmCbI3ch5mrXcP%2BAAl3JVMFaP24p2Cv%2FyRb94D5uE27SO9Bz%2B5Itba4vADtv3%2Btv2FMF9LJI6Zxr026UJYxDPNQMVpFTw2hiHd&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22schathub%22%7D%5D&tid=10' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

and this is the log in the Network:

[image: error]

Do I need to do anything extra besides all the steps listed in the tutorial to make this work?

Comment: Please show us the the relevant code of the application - [Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @radu-matei, the relevant code is in the linked tutorial. That is the minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: Open the developer console and check what is being logged and what requests are being sent and if they are successful. I remember that when I tried to use ServiceBus I misconfigured ServiceBus in the portal and nothing worked.

Comment: @Pawel, thanks for the help, I have added the error info. BTW: is it safe to just share my example Cloud Service url here? May be easier for others to check?

Comment: The problem is on the server side. Run/Debug your server locally connecting to service bus and see what exception you have and take it from there.

Comment: @Pawel, Debugged locally with the [Messaging With Topics sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-Started-Brokered-614d42e5). It turns out to be that my service bus is on "Basic" message tire (Although I created it with the Standard Price tire). I scaled it up to Standard and it works now. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [current Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/service-bus/), you need to set the Service bus to at least Standard tier to support Topics.

In this case, I did create my service bus choosing Standard tier, although it shows Standard on it's Overview page under the "Pricing tier" section, I have to specifically go to the settings and scaled it up from Basic to Standard. Which has solved the problem.